# How to ignore NA when I paste columns using data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, data.table, paste

I have a dataframe:

```
ID   value1  value2
1     wad     11
2     NA      NA
3     elf     1
```

When i do this:

```
dt[,new:=paste0(value1, value2)]
```

I get:

```
ID   value1  value2   new
1     wad     11      wad11
2     NA      NA      NANA
3     elf     1       elf1
```

How to ignore NA? And remove value1 and value2? I want to get:

```
ID   new
1    wad11
2    NA
3    elf1
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[,
  .(ID, new = do.call(paste, c(replace(.SD, is.na(.SD), ""), sep = ""))),
  .SDcols = patterns("^value")
]
```

gives

```
   ID   new
1:  1 wad11
2:  2
3:  3  elf1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = 1:3, value1 = c("wad", NA, "elf"), value2 = c(11L,
NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)       
setDT(df)
df[is.na(df)] <- ''
df[, new := paste0(value1, value2)][, .(ID, new)]
```

`tidyr::unite` has a one-liner solution to this :

```
tidyr::unite(df, new, value1, value2, na.rm = TRUE)

#  ID    new
#1  1 wad_11
#2  2       
#3  3  elf_1
```

Comment: thanks, i wrote in question using data.table

Comment: @reredf I updated the answer with `data.table`.

Comment: thanks, here  df[is.na(df)] <- '' you remove NA from all dataframe, however I need to remove it only from column "value1"

Comment: What about `value2` column? You want to keep the `NA` as it is there? You can define the `cols` as  `cols <- c('value1', 'value2')` and then replace `NA`. `df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), '')), .SDcols = cols]`
`

Comment: yeah right I need to remove NA from both columns, but not from other. its an example dataframe, in real i don't want to remove na from all columns

Comment: So the code in above comment will remove `NA` from only `value1` and `value2`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   transmute(ID, new = case_when(is.na(value1) & is.na(value2) ~ "",
      TRUE ~str_c(value1, value2, sep='_')))
#  ID    new
#1  1 wad_11
#2  2       
#3  3  elf_1
```